# how to make a form responsive when running a long loop in vb.net

Tags: loops, responsive-design

Im doing an application that analyze records from an excel file using a loop... while my application is doing this, my form is not responsive, I cant even drag my application. any idea how to make my application responsive?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in [this Microsoft link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/hh191443.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) you will find your solution. Use async/await to maintain your application responsive and do a work in background.

Answer (score 0):

I now know how to make my form responsive.. you just have to add `Application.DoEvents` inside the loop.. Thanks :D